# Google Sheets - How to make it so that the IF statement checks if the text is in a range

Tags: excel, google-sheets

So I tried `=IF(RegExMatch(A2,'Elite Fighters'!A2:A11),"YES","NO")` with Elite Fighters being the other sheet and has the range. It returned a `#VALUE! - An array value could not be found.

Same happened with `=IF(A2 = 'Elite Fighters'!A2:A11,"YES","NO")`.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=REGEXMATCH(C1,JOIN("|",$A$1:$A$3))`

[image]

1. `JOIN("|",$A$1:$A$3)` gives string "foo|baz|bar"
2. pipe line `|` is like OR in regex.

See more syntax of RegEx here:
https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ECGGvJA.png Doesn't work?

`=REGEXMATCH(A3,JOIN("|",'Elite Fighters'!A2:A11))` I typed this